# Migration trobules upgrading from vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb6-migration

I want to upgrade Vb5 code to Vb.net but I don't know how to upgrade this command
`strMsgDtl` and `vbCrLf` are string:

```
strMsgDtl = strMsgDtl & String(75, "-") & vbCrLf
```

What does the following command mean??

```
String(75, "-")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String(75,"-")` creates a string 75 characters long, made of the "-" character.

VB.Net equivalent would be `New String("-", 75)`